# How to ggplot two groups of income-segment populations and values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which has two types of 'groups,' the densities of which I would like to overlay on the same graph.

using ggplot, I tried to graph the density using the following two lines of code:

```
full$group <- factor(full$group)

ggplot(full, aes(x=income, fill=group)) + geom_density()
```

The issue with this is that the it does not take the frequency variable (freq) into account, and simply calculates the frequency itself.  That is an issue because there is exactly one row for every income-group combination.

I believe I have two options, each of which has a question:

a) Should I plot the graph using the way the data is currently formatted?  If so, how would I do that?

b) Should I reformat the data to make the frequency of each group/income combination equivalent to the freq variable assigned to it?  If so, how would I do that?

This is the kind of graph I would like, where "income" = "rating" and "group" = "cond":

[image]

dput of 'full':

```
full <- structure(list(income = c(10000, 19000, 29000, 39000, 49000, 75000, 99000, 1e+05, 10000, 19000,29000, 39000, 49000, 75000, 99000, 1e+05),
group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("one", "two"), class = "factor"),
freq = c(1237, 1791, 743, 291, 256, 212, 29, 11, 921, 1512, 614, 301, 209, 223, 48, 1)), .Names = c("income", "group", "freq"),
row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Almost impossible to understand what you mean "overlay densities on the same graph", or what type of plot you want (barplot? barplot with two dodged series?) **Post us a link to the type of plot you are trying to create!**

Comment: *"The issue with [plotting income vs as.factor(group)] is that it does not take the frequency variable (freq) into account, and simply calculates the frequency itself."*  If you want to plot freq, you must put it in the aes, or else do some stat transform on it. We don't know what type of plot you have in mind! "Plot freq" could mean 20 different things.

Comment: you're totally right, @smci .  Thanks for the input.  please see the updated post with an example of the plot i would like

Comment: On a sidebar, don't name your columns generic ggplot keywords like *'group'*, use descriptive terms e.g. *'income_grp'*

Comment: So I retitled it the more descriptive "How to ggplot two groups of income-segment populations and values". Clearer than saying "I need to plot freq" or "it must be a density-plot".

Comment: thanks @smci.  It can be tough to word these questions sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the observations by their frequency with

```
ggplot(full[rep(1:nrow(full), full$freq),]) + 
geom_density(aes(x=income, fill=group), color="black", alpha=.75, adjust=4)
```

Of course with your data this produces a pretty lousy plot

[image]

When estimating a density, your data should be observations from a continuous distribution. Here you really have a discrete distribution with repeated observations (in a true continuous distribution, the probability of seeing any value more than once is 0).

You could try to smooth this curve by setting the `adjust=` parameter to a number >1, (like 3 or 4). But really, your input data is just not in an appropriate form for a density plot. A bar plot would be a better choice. Maybe something like

```
ggplot(full, aes(as.factor(income), freq, fill=group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, MrFlick!  And that makes sense, shouldn't be looking for a continuous distribution with discrete data

Comment: @zebraintree: I did suggest "barplot with two dodged series?" earlier, but you *insisted* you wanted a density-plot... sigh.... refund crystal ball...

Comment: This is a total kludge though (repeating observations by their frequency)... sounds like it needs some stat_... transformation. See Statistics http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ Check e.g. `stat_bin(width...)`